# Manipulação e grid, hbox e vbox no pyqt4

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt-4

Sou principiante e estou fazendo uma interface grafica co a ajuda do pyqt4. Preciso adicionar duas colunas de botões ali onde só há uma, mas, toda vez que tento, o bottão vai para a direita e estraga as proporções.[image: ali] Alguém consegue me ajudar?  O que tenho até agora é isto:

```
self.main_frame = qg.QWidget()
self.area_canvas()
self.create_toolbox() 
self.botao_enviar = qg.QPushButton('ENVIAR')
self.botao_salvarr = qg.QPushButton('SALVAR')
self.botao_restaurar = qg.QPushButton("RESTAURAR")
self.botao_criar = qg.QPushButton(_tr("CRIAR"))
grid = qg.QGridLayout()
grid.addWidget(self.canvas,0,0,5,4)
grid.addWidget(self.botao_enviarr,0,4) 
grid.addWidget(self.botao_salvar,1,4)
grid.addWidget(self.botao_restaurar,2,4) 
grid.addWidget(self.botao_criar,3,4)
grid.addWidget(self.toolBox,4,4)
grid.addWidget(self.chk_id_pontos,6,0)
grid.addWidget(self.chk_id_barras,6,1)

self.main_frame.setLayout(grid)
self.setCentralWidget(self.main_frame)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo bem simples de como usar duas colunas com QGridLayout:

```
self.botao_enviar = qg.QPushButton('ENVIAR')
self.botao_salvar = qg.QPushButton('SALVAR')
self.botao_restaurar = qg.QPushButton('RESTAURAR')
self.botao_criar = qg.QPushButton('CRIAR')
self.botao_enviar2 = qg.QPushButton('ENVIAR2')
self.botao_salvar2 = qg.QPushButton('SALVAR2')
self.botao_restaurar2 = qg.QPushButton('RESTAURAR2')
self.botao_criar2 = qg.QPushButton('CRIAR2')

grid = qg.QGridLayout()
grid.addWidget(self.canvas,0,0,5,1)
grid.addWidget(self.botao_enviar,0,1) 
grid.addWidget(self.botao_salvar,1,1)
grid.addWidget(self.botao_restaurar,2,1) 
grid.addWidget(self.botao_criar,3,1)
grid.addWidget(self.botao_enviar2,0,2) 
grid.addWidget(self.botao_salvar2,1,2)
grid.addWidget(self.botao_restaurar2,2,2) 
grid.addWidget(self.botao_criar2,3,2)
```

Note que aqui eu modifiquei para o `canvas` ocupar apenas uma coluna:

```
grid.addWidget(self.canvas,0,0,5,1)
```

Se o problema é controlar a proporção de cada parte, pode fazer assim:

```
grid.setColumnStretch(0,3) # coluna zero (a do canvas) vai ter proporção 3
grid.setColumnStretch(1,1) # coluna um (primeira fileira) vai ter proporção 1
grid.setColumnStretch(2,1) # coluna dois (segunda fileira) vai ter proporção 1
```

Resultado:

[image: screenshot com duas fileiras verticais de botões]

Lembre-se que nestes casos pode ser mais conveniente usar um HBox, neste HBox pode por um canvas e dois VBox. Aí em cada VBox você coloca os botões desejados.

Documentação:

- http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html
- http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qvboxlayout.html
- http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qhboxlayout.html

Comment: Serviu perfeitamente! Muitíssimo obrigada!!!